# Last time monitor setup was changed

Tags: display

Our second monitor, a hallway screen to show information in the office, was found stolen this morning. Evidently ripped out of the wall and just left all the cables behind.

Since the computer was left running, we were hoping it would be somehow possible to pin down the time of the act by looking at the last time the monitor setup was changed (since Windows does that automatically when an HDMI cable is plugged out).

If anyone got any further ideas how to help us, please share your knowledge! Any clue is appreciated.

Comment: Look at the event logs?

Comment: I neither know where those are nor what information they contain.

Comment: [What Is the Windows Event Viewer, and How Can I Use It?](https://www.howtogeek.com/123646/htg-explains-what-the-windows-event-viewer-is-and-how-you-can-use-it/)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that monitor removal is logged :/